# Microsoft Query SQL query question

Tags: sql

I am completely new to Microsoft Query.

I have the following tables defined:

```
FLEET_MASTERS Table        
- REG_NO
- FMS_ID

ODOMETERS Table                           
- ODO_ID 
- FMS_ID

ODOMETERS_READING Table
- ODO_ID          
- ODO_READING
- ODO_READING_DATE
- ODO_READING_TYPE
```

I need these information:

```
REG_NO, ODO_READING, max(ODO_READING DATE), ODO_READING_TYPE
```

But from one `REG_NO`, there may be multiple `ODO_READING` and `ODO_READING DATE`, I just need the `ODO_READING` with the most recent `ODO_READING DATE`.

Comment: This is no good, you need to provide the table schemas if you want any help...

Comment: Please try and use the code block in the text editor and re-format your question. Currently I can't understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select fm.REG_NO, odr.ODO_READING, odr.ODO_READING_DATE as MAX_READING_DATE, odr.ODO_READING_TYPE
from FLEET_MASTERS fm
inner join ODOMETERS od on fm.FMS_ID = od.FMS_ID
inner join  (
    select ODO_ID, max(odr.ODO_READING_DATE) as MAX_READING_DATE
    from ODOMETERS_READING
    group by ODO_ID
) odm
inner join ODOMETERS_READING odr on odm.ODO_ID = odr.ODO_ID and odm.MAX_READING_DATE = odr.ODO_READING
```

Answer (score 0):

From your mess of text above I'm assuming the following schema

```
CREATE TABLE FLEET_MASTERS
(
    FMS_ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    REG_NO VARCHAR(10)
)
CREATE TABLE ODOMETERS_READING
(
    OMR_ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    FMS_ID INT,
    ODO_READING INT,
    ODO_READING_DATE DATETIME,
    ODO_READING_TYPE INT
)
```

Given that schema the following query would give you what you want, assuming there's only one record per Reg_No for a given date/time:

```
SELECT
    FM.REG_NO,
    OMR.ODO_READING,
    OMR.ODO_READING_DATE,
    OMR.ODO_READING_TYPE
FROM FLEET_MASTERS FM
INNER JOIN ODOMETERS_READING OMR
    ON FM.FMS_ID = OMR.FMS_ID
WHERE OMR.ODO_READING_DATE = (
    SELECT MAX(OMR1.ODO_READING_DATE)
    FROM ODOMETERS_READING OMR1
    WHERE OMR1.FMS_ID = FM.FMS_ID
)
```

I think I have that syntax right, all off the top of my head, no SQL server handy to test it.